# If $-1$ is a sum of squares, then any element is a sum of squares

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, sums-of-squares

We have a field $F$ of characteristic different from $2$ in which there exist
$a_1, \dots, a_n$ such that
$$
a_1^2 + \dots + a_n^2 = -1.
$$

Prove that for any $c \in F$, there exist $b_1, \dots, b_k$ such that
$$
b_1^2 + \dots + b_k^2 = c.
$$

I have no idea where to start from. Would anybody give me a clue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$c=\left(\frac{c+1}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{c-1}2\right)^2
=\left(\frac{c+1}2\right)^2+(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)\left(\frac{c-1}2\right)^2.$$

Comment: Could not be more clear.. Thanks!